# Long time to hide view

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, xcode6

I have the following swift code that happens when a login button is pressed.

```
@IBAction func login(sender: UIButton)
{
    sender.hidden = true;
    self.loader.hidden = false;
    println("HIDDEN");
    sleep(2);        
}
```

However the login button takes a long time to actually become hidden, long after "HIDDEN" is printed to the console. I presume this is because of the simulated delay I have added with sleep(2) but I'm not sure how to make this sleep happen after the button is hidden.

Comment: Use GCD `dispatch_after`

Comment: You shouldn't sleep in button responders; this will cause your application to be unresponsive during this time. What are you really trying to accomplish with the sleep?

Comment: simulate the time it would take to authenticate with a remote server

Comment: @MatteoPacini can I get an example in swift that would cause the sleep to only occur after hidden?

Comment: @Ben_hawk It is a really bad practice to use `sleep()`, especially on the main thread. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: simulate the time it would take to authenticate with a remote server before presenting the home view controller - dev only not for production

Comment: You need to perform the selector on the main thread instead of the secondary thread for the UI to respond quickly. Also add the code in the completion block to execute the code that you want to activate once the operation is completed.

Answer (score 1):

The comments lead me to this solution which works asynchronously and thus not blocking the main thread which was causing the hide action to pause.

```
@IBAction func login(sender: UIButton)
{
    sender.hidden = true;
    self.loader.hidden = false;

    dispatch_after(
        dispatch_time(
            DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
            Int64(3 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
        ),
        dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("homeNavigation") as UIViewController;
            self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil);
    })



}
```